# is it possible to transfer data from one table to several tables,those tables have created from that data contained table

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `Vehicle_tbl` in mysql database, having fields

```
vehicle_id
vehicle name
vehicle_desc
vehicle_modal
modal_desc
vehicle_dealer
dealer_address
qty
```

for a new use I divide the database into four table

```
tbl_vehicle (vid,vname,vdesc)
tbl_vehicle_modal (vmodid,vmod,vid,vmoddesc)
tbl_vehicle_dealer (vdid,vdname,vdaddress)
main_Table (id,vid,vmodid,vdid,qty)
```

a huge number of data I have already stored in my first created table.

Is there any easy method to transfer all data from first table to my newly created database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below code, for more [info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_vehicle (vid,vname,vdesc)
  SELECT vehicle_id, vehicle name, vehicle_desc
  FROM Vehicle_tbl
```

**EDIT:**

```
INSERT INTO main_Table (id,vid,vmodid,vdid,qty)
  SELECT tbl_vehicle.vid, tbl_vehicle_modal.vmodid, tbl_vehicle_dealer.vdid, Vehicle_table.qty
  FROM tbl_vehicle, tbl_vehicle_modal, tbl_vehicle_dealer, Vehicle_table
  WHERE tbl_vehicle.vid = tbl_vehicle_modal.vid 
  AND tbl_vehicle.vid = Vehicle_table.vid
```

Comment: vehicle_id i given in newly created table, tbl_vehicle it is autoincrement . i have inserted all vehicle_names_to vehicle table, i want to insert vehicle_id to main_table instead of each vehicle name, thank you

Comment: I just edited my answer, I'm not sure about the `WHERE` clause, since I don't know the relation between each table.. Hope it helps..

Comment: tank you, its working, but while I add more than three forign key to main_table someny duplicate rows are appearing,is there any option to filter it? ,thank you

Comment: Make sure the `WHERE` clause already satisfied your expected result, because I don't really understand your tables relation.. You can try to run the `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...` statement individually, then if you satisfied with the result, put it back below the `SELECT` statement.. 
Don't forget to check it as right answer and up vote.. ^^